# Translate number words to numbers in all languages in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a function that converts words to numbers **in english** and I have tried to create a "global" function to account for all languages that have an input array. Unfortunately I'm not having any luck.

Considering I have two arrays for different languages (I got this from a different SO question) how would I go to put it to work in **all languages that have an array**?

```
var BR = {"BRAZILIAN"}

var EN = {
    'zero': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10,
    'eleven': 11,
    'twelve': 12,
    'thirteen': 13,
    'fourteen': 14,
    'fifteen': 15,
    'sixteen': 16,
    'seventeen': 17,
    'eighteen': 18,
    'nineteen': 19,
    'twenty': 20,
    'thirty': 30,
    'forty': 40,
    'fifty': 50,
    'sixty': 60,
    'seventy': 70,
    'eighty': 80,
    'ninety': 90
};

var EN_Magnitude = {
    'thousand':     1000,
    'million':      1000000,
    'billion':      1000000000,
    'trillion':     1000000000000,
    'quadrillion':  1000000000000000,
    'quintillion':  1000000000000000000,
    'sextillion':   1000000000000000000000,
    'septillion':   1000000000000000000000000,
    'octillion':    1000000000000000000000000000,
    'nonillion':    1000000000000000000000000000000,
    'decillion':    1000000000000000000000000000000000,
};

function feach(w,n,g) {

    w = w.toLowerCase();

    var x = EN[w];

    if (x != null) {
       return g = g + x;
    }
    else if (w == "hundred") {
       return g = g * 100;
    }
    else {
        x = EN_Magnitude[w];
        if (x != null) {
            n = n + g * x
            g = 0;
        }
        else {
            return w;
        }
    }
    return n+g;
}

module.exports.text2num = function (word) {
    word = word.toString().toLowerCase();
    n = 0;
    g = 0;
    return feach(word,n,g);
  };
```

Is there any library in nodejs for this? Can anyone help me sort this out?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is a [words-to-numbers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/words-to-numbers) library

Comment: @M.Sallam Thank you, that is amazing. But have you actually read my question, considering it explicitly says `in all languages`?

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/daraeman/word-to-number-node here index.js is the server code where you will find language setting function

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it with more than one language is just adding the language as a key and the numbers object as a value instead of making an object for each language.

#### ** This solution will only work with languages that follow the same rules of word numbers as English.... You will need to implement the rules of other languages which do not (German for example)

basic function :

**t2n.js file :**

```
var units = {
  'en': {
    'zero': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10,
    'eleven': 11,
    'twelve': 12,
    'thirteen': 13,
    'fourteen': 14,
    'fifteen': 15,
    'sixteen': 16,
    'seventeen': 17,
    'eighteen': 18,
    'nineteen': 19
  }
}

var tens = {
  'en': {
    'twenty': 20,
    'thirty': 30,
    'forty': 40,
    'fifty': 50,
    'sixty': 60,
    'seventy': 70,
    'eighty': 80,
    'ninety': 90
  }
}

var magnitude = {
  'en': {
    'hundred': 100,
    'thousand': 1000,
    'million': 1000000,
    'billion': 1000000000,
    'trillion': 1000000000000,
    'quadrillion': 1000000000000000,
    'quintillion': 1000000000000000000,
    'sextillion': 1000000000000000000000,
    'septillion': 1000000000000000000000000,
    'octillion': 1000000000000000000000000000,
    'nonillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000,
    'decillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000000
  }
}

function getNumber (text, language) {
  let textArray = text.toLowerCase().replace(/ and /g, ' ').split(' ')
  let temp = null
  let result = 0
  for (let word of textArray) {
    if (units[language].hasOwnProperty(word)) {
      if (textArray.indexOf(word) === textArray.length - 1) {
        result += (temp === null) ? units[language][word] : temp + units[language][word]
      } else {
        temp = (temp === null) ? units[language][word] : temp + units[language][word]
      }
    } else if (tens[language].hasOwnProperty(word)) {
      if (textArray.indexOf(word) === textArray.length - 1) {
        result += units[language][word]
      } else {
        temp = tens[language][word]
      }
    } else if (magnitude[language].hasOwnProperty(word)) {
      result += magnitude[language][word] * temp
      temp = null
    } else {
      return 'wrong text'
    }
  }
  return result
}
module.exports.text2num = getNumber
```

**app.js file:**

```
var { text2num } = require('./t2n')
console.log(text2num('one million five hundred and twenty nine', 'en'))
console.log(text2num('twenty thousand five hundred and sixty nine', 'en'))
console.log(text2num('one Quintillion one quadrillion one trillion and one hundred', 'en'))
```